# In Jupiter lab, Kernel is stopping when executing a code related to tensor flow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

Is there a particular version of python that works with tensor flow. I am trying import tensor flow dependencies for a project. Just after I run that cell in my Jupiter notebook, the kernel stops working. I am very new to tensor flow.

NOTE - Using python version 3.9

Installing tensor flow using this command

`!pip install tensorflow==2.6.1 opencv-python matplotlib`

These are standard dependencies
`import cv2 import os import random import numpy as np from matplotlib import pyplot as plt`

This is where the kernel stops working

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer, Conv2D, Dense, MaxPooling2D, Input, Flatten
import tensorflow as tf 

gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for gpu in gpus: 
     tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
```

Comment: Do you config cuda toolkit after installiing tensorflow? Have you GPU attached in your system?

Comment: should work perfectly fine on 3.9 or 3.10.  I currently use 3.10 and it works.

Comment: There could be problems with `keras` and `tensorflow` version mismatch in your system environment while importing `tensorflow.keras` apis. Please try again the above code after installing the same version of keras as installed tensorflow version using `!pip install keras==2.6` and let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you.